# I want to get only count from the control file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to get only count from a control file. The control file's name is `AA.dat` (for example) and the data in the file will be as follows.

```
AA.dat  200
```

From the above file I want to pick only the value 200. When I try to use the `cut` command I am not able to get the result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with **`grep`**:

```
cnt=$(grep -o -m1 '[0-9]*$' AA.dat)
```

- `[0-9]*$` - match any number of digits `[0-9]*` at the end of the line `$`

---

```
echo "$cnt"
200
```

Answer (score 0):

Or equally simply with `read` if you know the file format beforehand, e.g.

```
read -r stuff cnt <AA.dat
```

Where you simply read the first line in the file into two variables. `stuff` will hold the first whitespace separated string, `cnt` will hold the remainder of the line `200` in your case, e.g.:

```
$ read -r stuff cnt <AA.dat; echo "cnt: $cnt"
cnt: 200
```

`awk` is another easy way to access the second column of data. In its simplest form it will output the second column for all lines (in your case 1-line):

```
$ awk '{print $2}' AA.dat
200
```

shell also provides for *parameter expansion* with *substring removal* and *substring replacement*. Both can be use to isolate `200` after reading the full line into a single variable.

Shell depending (with bash, etc), you can also read the line into an array and then make use of the element of interest. There are a number of ways to handle it.

Take your pick. The only note would be using a shell builtin prevents invoking a separate subshell for whatever utility you use instead. If you are calling the utility repeatedly within a loop on a large file -- utilities (as opposed to builtins) can dramatically increase the script run-time. If you just call it a handful of times, the differences is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `cut`

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 < AA.dat
200
```

using `awk`,

```
$ awk '{print $2}' AA.dat
200
```